# Fatal error "Allowed memory size" while run setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: magento2, setup, memory, deploy

I am trying to setup Magento 2.0 (community) in a WAMP server and I am getting the error below **all the time** while I run the command for deploy the assets static due to symlink issues at Windows environments:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 64 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\magento\vendor\oyejorge\less.php\lib\Less\Visitor\processExtends.php on line 445

I have setup `memory_limit` as `-1` (no limit) but this takes no changes. I don't know what else to do in this case since the issue goes beyond my PHP knowledge and setting that value to no limit should do the job unless I need to install something else to get this working. Any advices? Any workaround?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

quick solution add memory size in the command :

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

change 6G to what you want

Comment: FWIW, we recommend 768M for normal use and 2G for testing. Your mileage might vary... [example](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html#instgde-prereq-timezone)

Comment: I have only a template installed and a single product, setting 2G still gets the  memory error. Why is this damn thing so memory consuming?

Comment: php -d memory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
. There should be a space after -d and before memory_limit

Answer (score 1):

In dev mode I managed to solve this issue by running the following command: 
`rm -rf pub/static/* var/di var/generation var/cache var/page_cache`

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory limit to update .php.ini file

If you have access to your php.ini file or can create one in the root, you can globally increase your allocated memory.

```
;adjust memory limit
memory_limit = 6G
max_execution_time = 36000
max_input_time = 36000
```

If you not want to update .php.ini file then use below command

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```