# Unable to fetch css in magento2 after magento2 upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, upgrade, less-css, magento2.1.6

I update my Magento 2.0.1 to 2.1.6 and it updates successfully.
The problem is from **frontside CSS** are not working correctly but in admin side, it is working good.[image]

What i do to update magento is

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.0.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/generation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

After doing this all process when i do

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

It shows some css errors like

Compilation from source: /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less

Compilation from source:

```
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-l.less
variable @color-text-red is undefined in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/WeltPixel_Quickview/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 65, column 11
63|     .page-title{
64|       font-size: @indent__base * 1.05 !important;
65|       color: @color-text-red !important;
66|     }
67|     .product-info-price{
68|       .old-price{

.

Compilation from source: /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-l.less
variable @color-text-red is undefined in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/WeltPixel_Quickview/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 65, column 11
63|     .page-title{
64|       font-size: @indent__base * 1.05 !important;
65|       color: @color-text-red !important;
66|     }
67|     .product-info-price{
68|       .old-price{

.........................................................................................................

Compilation from source: /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/css/styles-m.less
variable @color-text-red is undefined in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/WeltPixel_Quickview/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 65, column 11
63|     .page-title{
64|       font-size: @indent__base * 1.05 !important;
65|       color: @color-text-red !important;
66|     }
67|     .product-info-price{
68|       .old-price{

.

Compilation from source: /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-l.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/fuelpump-new/theme/en_US/css/styles-l.less
variable @color-text-red is undefined in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/fuelpump-new/theme/en_US/WeltPixel_Quickview/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 65, column 11
63|     .page-title{
64|       font-size: @indent__base * 1.05 !important;
65|       color: @color-text-red !important;
66|     }
67|     .product-info-price{
68|       .old-price{

......................................................

Compilation from source: /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/css/styles-m.less
variable @color-text-red is undefined in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/WeltPixel_Quickview/css/source/_module.less in _module.less on line 65, column 11
63|     .page-title{
64|       font-size: @indent__base * 1.05 !important;
65|       color: @color-text-red !important;
66|     }
67|     .product-info-price{
68|       .old-price{

...............PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/ReadFactory.php on line 40

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Directory/ReadFactory.php on line 40

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Compilation from source: /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/styles-m.less

Compilation from source: 
frontend/fuelpump-new/theme/en_US/css/styles-m.less
variable @color-text-red is undefined in file /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/var/view_preprocessed/css/frontend/fuelpump-new/theme/en_US/css/source/_navigation.less in _navigation.less on line 26, column 30
24| 
25|     .nav-sections {
26|         .lib-css(background, @color-text-red);
27|     display: inline-block;
28|     float: left;
29|     width: 100%;

........................................................PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1052672 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Bundle.php on line 192

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1052672 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/demofuel/vendor/magento/framework/View/Asset/Bundle.php on line 192
```

Comment: Check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97209/magento-2-css-and-javascript-not-loading-from-correct-folder

Comment: how did i know that it is duplicate or not @TejabhagavanKollepara

Answer (score 0):

Clear cache and deploy static content if you are not in developer mode

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Check the permissions in pub folder too

Comment: I already try this.

Comment: First of all thank you ruben but when i do static content deploy i show some css errors which i mention above in my question can you help me on that

Comment: Seems to be a memory_limit error. Check this post or change the php.ini configuration.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-while-run-setupstatic-contentdeploy