# Internal Server Error when magento2 website host in SubDomain

Tags: magento2, cpanel, godaddy

I got Following type of error

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
>   misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at
>   webmaster@nn.packparadise.com to inform them of the time this error
>   occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Thank you in Advance

[image]

Comment: most likely to do with Apache permissions and the .htaccess file as http://nn.packparadise.com/error_log returns a 404 error and not a 500 error

Comment: thank you for your reply ,but how can do apache permission in godday

Comment: DO you have ssh access?

Comment: yes i have ssh access

Comment: i got this type of error "Invalid command '<IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"  in error log

Comment: and i got error in "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 2097160 bytes) in /home/yn64mexz44ya/public_html/nn/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/lib/Less/Output.php on line 27"  in nn.packparadise.com/error_log file

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97749/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-while-run-setupstatic-contentdeploy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743921/magento-ifversion-perhaps-misspelled-or-defined-by-a-module-not-included-in-t

Comment: Thank you i will check